# Invalid or unitialized Zip object

Tags: php, zip

```
if(isset($_POST['items'])) {
    // open zip
    $zip_path = 'downloadSelected/download.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if ($zip->open($zip_path, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {
       die ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file.");
     }

     foreach ($_POST['items'] as $path) {
        // generate filename to add to zip
        $filepath = 'downloads/' . $path . '.zip';
        if (file_exists($filepath)) {
                $zip->addFile($filepath, $path . '.zip') or die ("ERROR: Could not add the file $filename");
        }
        else {
                die("File $filepath doesnt exit");
                }
        $zip->close();
       } }
```

I am getting *Warning: `ZipArchive::addFile()` [function.ZipArchive-addFile]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object*. what could be problem? I tried many methods but in vain.
I am able to create and initiate download when I select one file. However, I get above error when I select more than one file.

Comment: It appears you try to create a zip archive from selected physical files, most likely to send it to the requesting browser afterwards. Take a look at http://pablotron.org/software/zipstream-php/, works like charm. There is also an enhanced version available which saves created zip files to a temporary file when a certain size limit is exceeded. If you can use another archive format (less outdated than zip, with a more intelligent algorithm, maybe Tar-Archives using a gzip compression), then you don't have to worry about the archive size at all, since those archives work in a real stream mode.

Comment: @arkascha Whilst zipstream may be a useful alternative, your comment may be misleading as it is entirely tangential to the actual question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The power of indenting correctly!

You are closing your zip file inside your loop.

If I re-format your code it becomes obvious.

Corrected code follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['items'])) {
  // open zip
  $zip_path = 'downloadSelected/download.zip';
  $zip = new ZipArchive();

  if ($zip->open($zip_path, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {
    die ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file.");
  }

  foreach ($_POST['items'] as $path) {

    // generate filename to add to zip
    $filepath = 'downloads/' . $path . '.zip';

    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
      $zip->addFile($filepath, $path . '.zip') or die ("ERROR: Could not add the file $filename");
    } else {
      die("File $filepath doesnt exit");
    }
  }

  $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Please also note that in PHP 5.6 at least (up to 5.6.12), it seems that you must ensure that the ZIP path does not point to a non-ZIP file, or you must delete it. See my question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694148/ziparchivegetstatusstring-invalid-or-uninitialized-zip-object

Answer (score 12):

the library itself gives you a code to see why it fails:

```
$ZIP_ERROR = [
  ZipArchive::ER_EXISTS => 'File already exists.',
  ZipArchive::ER_INCONS => 'Zip archive inconsistent.',
  ZipArchive::ER_INVAL => 'Invalid argument.',
  ZipArchive::ER_MEMORY => 'Malloc failure.',
  ZipArchive::ER_NOENT => 'No such file.',
  ZipArchive::ER_NOZIP => 'Not a zip archive.',
  ZipArchive::ER_OPEN => "Can't open file.",
  ZipArchive::ER_READ => 'Read error.',
  ZipArchive::ER_SEEK => 'Seek error.',
];

$result_code = $zip->open($zip_fullpath);
if( $result_code !== true ){
   $msg = isset($ZIP_ERROR[$result_code])? $ZIP_ERROR[$result_code] : 'Unknown error.';
   return ['error'=>$msg];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you cannot OR the open mode flags, you can only open in one mode. Check the file exists first and set the mode on open appropriately and see if that helps.

Comment: My code, works when I select single file and perform this operation (of zip creation), however when I select more than one file, it gives the above error.

Comment: Alternative (correct) answer given on a new post. Considering deleting this one if there are no objections...

Answer (score 0):

It also is possible that you are using `php://output` as filename (not for question author, but anyone who searching for this error), this is not supported by ZipArchive.

If you need to output zip file, then save it to temp file and use `readfile` function afterwards.